# get address of new contract from contract factory

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, web3-providers

i need to deploy a rental contract at runtime whenever user want's to start the contract. for this purpose i have acontract factory. here is the actual code for facotry

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;
import './RentalContract.sol';


contract contractFactory {
  address[] public contracts;


  function getContractCount() public returns(uint) {
    return contracts.length;
  }

  function newContract(uint _rent, uint _security_deposit, string _house, address _owner, address _tenant)
  public payable returns(address)  {
    Rental c = new Rental(_rent, _security_deposit, _house, _owner, _tenant);
    contracts.push(c);
    return c;
  }
}
```

this function newContract is suposed to return the address of new rental contract. Here is the my angular service which calls this function to get the address of new contract.

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import * as Web3 from 'web3';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
    import {observable} from "rxjs/symbol/observable";
    import {reject} from "q";

    const FactoryArtifacts = require('/home/work/angularplustruffle/angular4-truffle-starter-dapp/build/contracts/contractFactory.json');
    const contract = require('truffle-contract');
    const RentalArtifacts = require('/home/work/angularplustruffle/angular4-truffle-starter-dapp/build/contracts/Rental.json');

    declare let require: any;
    declare let window: any;

    @Injectable()
    export class ContractsService {
      ContractFactory = contract(FactoryArtifacts);
      Rental = contract(RentalArtifacts);
      private web3: any;
      public acc_no: any = 5;

      constructor() {
        if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
          // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
          this.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
          this.ContractFactory.setProvider(window.web3.currentProvider);
          this.Rental.setProvider(window.web3.currentProvider);

          /* if (this.web3.version.network !== '4') {
            alert('Please connect to the Rinkeby network');
          } */
        } else {
          console.warn(
            'Please use a dapp browser like mist or MetaMask plugin for chrome'
          );
        }
      }

 public deployRentalContract(rent, security_deposit, house, owner, tenant): Observable<any> {
    let meta;
      return Observable.create( observer => {
        this.ContractFactory
          .deployed()
          .then( instance => {
              meta = instance;
              console.log('data to send:' + "rent " + rent, " security " + security_deposit + " house" + house + " owner" + owner + " tenant" + tenant);
              return meta.newContract(rent, security_deposit, house, owner, tenant, {from: this.web3.eth.accounts[0],
                gas:1000000, value: this.web3.toWei(0.01, "ether")});
          })
          .then(value => {
            console.log("value is");
            console.log(value);
            observer.next(value);
            observer.complete();
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            observer.error(e);
          });
      });
  }
}
```

but instead of getting an address i am getting following response
[image]

how can i get actual address instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The response you are getting is the receipt of the transaction. Return values from functions which create transactions, to my knowledge, can only be `true` or `false`.

However, you should be able to emit an event containing the address of the contract after it is created in the factory.

```
event ContractCreated(address newAddress);
```

Then, within your `newContract()` function, after you create a new contract, you can do:

```
ContractCreated(c);
```

This will create an event which you can then search for to find your address. I believe this event will also appear in the receipt object from web3, so you may be able to obtain the address from there as well.

Comment: thanks a lot. i was struggling with it for almost last 5 hours. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Zack's answer above, you can get the address of the contract using the address keyword. So the event that you emit will be

```
emit ContractCreated(address(c));
```